# Duplicate column name in table storage source in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

**Setup:**
1. I have a Azure table storage table with the following schema

```
PartitionKey
RowKey
TimeStamp [Generated By Azure table storage automatically]
DataField1
TimeStamp [Field added by code]
```

I have added this table as a source in my data factory.

**Issue**
When i try to publish this data set, it gives me an error saying
`The name 'TIMESTAMP' is duplicated in 2 Schema`

I tried removing the code generated TimeStamp in the `structure` of data. But the error still persists.

Please do suggest any way to import this dataset.

Comment: How did you remove the code generated TimeStamp?Just set them `null` value will not be  effective, they are still there and can be mapped by azure data factory.

Comment: i meant the "structure" property in the arm template of the data factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the ADF visual authoring tool? 
Just checking the duplicated column and clicking delete button should work.

In you case you said you already remove the column but the error still exists, I suspect that you import the schema again before publishing somehow, thus the schema structure change is reverted. If that's not the case, please provide more details.

Comment: This sounds so simple now. Not sure how i missed the delete option. Thanks @Li

Comment: While we are at it, I also have a column that contains a stringified json.[Basically a complex object was serialised as string]. When i import this , the csv file gets messed up. Do you have any recommendation for this ?

Comment: The csv file gets messed up mainly because it's not parsed well. Not sure whether it will help, but it's nice to check the [file format doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs).